# React brokes up if builds as NPM package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, npm-publish

I want to create an NPM package. The code I use is working - I tested it inside another project. But when I try to separate this code from my the project everything brokes up with error

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Here's package.json

```
{
  "name": "some-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

And the code of the package:

```
import { VFC, useMemo } from 'react';

export const someHOC = (Component: VFC) => {
    useMemo(() => [], []);

    return Component;
};
```

I build this code with `tsc` without any flags.

---

And for some reason I can't use this package:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { someHOC } from 'some-name';

const Some = someHOC(() => <div>asdasd1</div>);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Some/>,
    document.querySelector('#root'),
);
```

---

Could you please explain me where am I wrong?

Comment: Do you use webpack? I guess you have two copies of react: first one in the npm package and the second one in the consumer. Is it your case?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The package's React is a peer dependency

Comment: Please try to add this to your webpack.config:
externals: {
 'react': 'react',
 'react-dom' : 'reactDOM'
}

Comment: Oh, yeah, thank you. The problem was with imports and linking. For some reason peer dependecies work incorrectly. When I try to run published version of the packages everything was OK

Comment: Cool, you're welcome :)